# dplyr left_join using existing column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to join data.frames using `dplyr` `left_join`.
More detailedly, I have a data.frame with several rows

```
table <- structure(list(species = c("Adelastes hylonomos", "Adelophryne adiastola", 
                                    "Adelophryne gutturosa", "Adelphobates quinquevittatus", "Adenomera andreae"
), Autor = c("Zweifel, 1986", "Hoogmoed and Lescure, 1984", "Hoogmoed and Lescure, 1984", 
             "(Steindachner, 1864)", "(Mí_ller, 1923)")), .Names = c("species", 
                                                                     "Autor"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
> head(table)
                       species                      Autor
1          Adelastes hylonomos              Zweifel, 1986
2        Adelophryne adiastola Hoogmoed and Lescure, 1984
3        Adelophryne gutturosa Hoogmoed and Lescure, 1984
4 Adelphobates quinquevittatus       (Steindachner, 1864)
5            Adenomera andreae            (Mí_ller, 1923)
```

And I want to attach other dataframes that only have one row at a concrete position, as given by a species name. These could be two of these data.frames:

```
vect1 <- structure(list(species = "Adelophryne adiastola", rango.iucn = "Si", 
                        rango.legend = 2L, rango.area = 17.95164829), .Names = c("species", 
                                                                                 "rango.iucn", "rango.legend", "rango.area"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -1L))
vect2 <- structure(list(species = "Adelophryne gutturosa", rango.iucn = "Si", 
                        rango.legend = 2L, rango.area = 20.94913312), .Names = c("species", 
                                                                                 "rango.iucn", "rango.legend", "rango.area"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -1L))
> head(vect1)
                species rango.iucn rango.legend rango.area
1 Adelophryne adiastola         Si            2   17.95165
> head(vect2)
                species rango.iucn rango.legend rango.area
1 Adelophryne gutturosa         Si            2   20.94913
```

I was expecting the function to create only once the columns and, later, recycle them to add the other species data. But that is not what happens: it attach a symbol (.x / .y):

```
> table <- table %>% left_join(vect1, by="species")
> table <- table %>% left_join(vect2, by="species")
> head(table)
                       species                      Autor rango.iucn.x
1          Adelastes hylonomos              Zweifel, 1986         <NA>
2        Adelophryne adiastola Hoogmoed and Lescure, 1984           Si
3        Adelophryne gutturosa Hoogmoed and Lescure, 1984         <NA>
4 Adelphobates quinquevittatus       (Steindachner, 1864)         <NA>
5            Adenomera andreae            (Mí_ller, 1923)         <NA>
  rango.legend.x rango.area.x rango.iucn.y rango.legend.y rango.area.y
1             NA           NA         <NA>             NA           NA
2              2     17.95165         <NA>             NA           NA
3             NA           NA           Si              2     20.94913
4             NA           NA         <NA>             NA           NA
5             NA           NA         <NA>             NA           NA
```

Am I using the wrong function or am I missing something?
I really would like to use a dplyr function.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems like you might want to stack `vect1` and `vect2` and then join that to `table`.  See `bind_rows` as an option.

Comment: @aosmith thanks! That might work... but, besides the example I provided, I actually want to join several hundred of `vect`'s, some with the same names, some that might have additional columns... Also, some species might be missing their `vect`, and the row filled with `NAs` will be a nice output for that. So, maybe I do need an option that let attach the right dataframes to the main one to ve operative across a for loop...

Comment: Maybe add in your desired output and make your example `vect` a bit more complicated?  `bind_rows` plus `left_join` still seem like the right tools to me.  Note that `bind_rows` will keep all columns even if some datasets don't have them.  It can also work with lists, which might be useful as it would make sense to store hundreds of `vect`'s in a list.  A `left_join`to `table` after stacking all the `vect` would still give you a rows filled with `NA`.